# Labelling only one point on a coordinate axis (pgfplots)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

I want a grid on the whole plane like I have, but I don't want labels on the coordinate axes (other than at x/y=1) or the blank spaces that are seen in the MWE. How do I accomplish this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} %y=x^-4

\begin{axis}[grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize},
x=0.4cm,y=0.4cm,clip=false,
xmin=-4,xmax=4,xtick={-3,-2,-1,1,2,3},xticklabels={,,,1,,},
ymin=-4,ymax=4,ytick={-3,-2,-1,1,2,3},yticklabels={,,,1,,},
xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
samples=200]

\addplot[domain=-4:-0.250,<->,>=latex] {x^-1};
\addplot[domain=0.250:4,<->,>=latex] {x^-1};
\node[label={270:{\(y=x^{-1}\)}},inner sep=4pt] at (axis cs:0,-4) {};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove x and y tick labels and use extra x/y ticks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} %y=x^-4

\begin{axis}[grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
extra x tick style={ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize},xticklabel={1}},
extra y tick style={ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize},yticklabel={1}},
x=0.4cm,y=0.4cm,clip=false,
xmin=-4,xmax=4,xtick={-3,-2,-1,1,2,3},xticklabels={\empty},
ymin=-4,ymax=4,ytick={-3,-2,-1,1,2,3},yticklabels={\empty},
extra x ticks={1}, extra y ticks={1},
xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
samples=200]

\addplot[domain=-4:-0.250,<->,>=latex] {x^-1};
\addplot[domain=0.250:4,<->,>=latex] {x^-1};
\node[label={270:{\(y=x^{-1}\)}},inner sep=4pt] at (axis cs:0,-4) {};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add

```
xticklabel style={fill opacity=0, text opacity=1},
yticklabel style={fill opacity=0, text opacity=1},
```

to the `axis` options.

[image]